# What is the correct way to use variables in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to reference an element once and then reuse it threw out my code but I'm not sure the correct way. Below is what I tried but it only works in some places. (EDIT: works, had an error farther up in my code, but I'm still curious if this is the best practice or not.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var image = $("#content img");
  image.wrap("<span />");
  image.hover(function(){}, function(){});
});
```

Comment: I had another error that was causing this not to work, after fixing the error it worked fine. However I'm still curious if this is a good practice. I see below someone mentioned making a JQuery object, var $image, is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me... Making a local variable inside the callback, like you did, is always going to be better than using a global object. However, the beauty of jQuery is that you can shorten your code to not even use a variable at all:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#content img").wrap("<span />").hover(function(){}, function(){});
});
```

This is called [chaining](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+chaining) and allows you to "chain" methods of the jQuery object together in one expression. But if you really need the variable for whatever reason, I see nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

That should work.  What indication are you getting that `image.hover()` is not working?

As a side note: this certainly isn't a standard, but when I'm doing stuff like this, I preface variables that are jQuery objects with a $, so: `var $image = $("#content img");` - just helps me keep track of what is a jQuery object.

Comment: It works for me too.  Are you trying to use this.css(), this.attr(), etc. within the hover functions, because that won't work.  You still have to use it like: $(this).

Comment: Thanks, I did not even realize I could do that.

Comment: Is this a fairly standard practice? I like it.

Answer (score 0):

[`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) should work fine. Inside the functions you pass into `hover()` you use `$(this)` to get at the element being hovered over. So:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image = $("#content img");
    image.wrap("<span />");
    image.hover(function(){
        $(this).css({border:'5px solid red'});
    }, function(){
        $(this).css({border:'none'});
    });
});
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it written above, `var image` is a local variable scoped to the anonymous function being called onReady. So any calls to that variable outside the scope of the function will produce `ReferenceError`. In Javascript, prefixing variable instantiation with `var` labels it as a local variable whereas leaving it off makes a global variable (usually ill -advised). Consider the following (contrived) example:

```
(function() {
  global_variable    = "global";
  var local_variable = "local";

  console.debug(global_variable);
  console.debug(local_variable);
})();

console.debug(global_variable);
console.debug(local_variable);

// Produces:

global
local
global
ReferenceError: local_variable is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow you, Jared. If you have a look at the following JS Bin, I've (I think) duplicated your example, and it runs fine.

http://jsbin.com/izimi3/

Perhaps the issue is syntactical, or scope oriented?

Also, if this is literally the code (sans details, obviously), then I would suggest against using a variable to store this at all. Typically you'll want to use variables when you're going to be reusing a selector often (e.g. "$this = $(this)"), otherwise keeping the code simple enough as to use the selector you need in the moment may make things easier for you.

Anyway, I hope I read right and didn't just waste your time.